# Dynamic gridview column value dependent on another column value

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview that has three bound fields. "Date", which is the day a support ticket was added; "Date Fixed", which is the day a support ticket was resolved; and "Days Waited", which should be the number of days a ticket has gone unresolved.

Each row has a different date and could or could not have a dateFixed. I can use the RowDataBound event to calculate daysWaited from date and dateFixed, but I do not know how to then set daysWaited to the calculated value for each row.

I am using VB.NET and the .NET 4.0 framework.

Comment: Is this done in VB.Net OR ASP.Net?

Comment: Can't you make it part of you query to get the data?

Comment: @MrCoDeXer: It is ASP.NET using VB.NET in the code behind.

Comment: I gave you a method that works, but if you can make it part of your query it would be much better as @GuyNethery has mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are loading data, hopefully setting the datasource of the gridview. After you set the datasource, you can call this method. It will go through and compare dates on each row, it also checks if anything is there. This worked good during my testing. Hopefully you find this good for your use.

```
 Private Sub CalcDays()
    For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim stDate As Date
        Dim endDate As Date
        Dim daysPassed As Integer = -1

        If Not (GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text = "&nbsp;") Then
            stDate = DateTime.Parse(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text)
            endDate = DateTime.Parse(GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text)

            While (stDate <= endDate)
                stDate = stDate.AddDays(1)
                daysPassed += 1
            End While

            GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text = daysPassed.ToString
        Else
            GridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Text = "NA"
        End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

**Here's a screenshot of my test...**

[image: Screenshot]